# Flutter: How to open the App when notification arrives from FirebaseMessaging (without user action)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I'm working on a communication app, and currently implementing Video and Voice calls.
I want when a notification arrives to the app, I want the app to open on specific screen.
I've done something like that by showing a notification and the app opens when user press on the notification.
But when a call arrives I want the app open without the **action** of the user.

I've tried to open the app with [external_app_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher) but it doesn't open.
Here is the code.

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print('Message In background: ${message.data}');
  LaunchApp.openApp(androidPackageName: "com.example.chat_app"); 
  
}
```

This is the code I tried to do to open the app.
And here is my old code that shows a notification(It works without any problem)

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print('Message In background: ${message.data}');
  var initializationSettingsAndroid =
      const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  var initializationSettingsIOs = const IOSInitializationSettings();
  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    iOS: initializationSettingsIOs,
  );

  //when the app is in foreground state and you click on notification.
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: (String? payload) {
    if (payload != null) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(payload);
      goToNextScreen(data, true);
    }
  });
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      Random().nextInt(1000000000),
      message.data['title'],
      message.data["body"],
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description,
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            playSound: true,
            sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("ringtone1"),
            fullScreenIntent: true),
      ),
      payload: json.encode(message.data));
}
```

Comment: "when a call arrives I want the app open without the action of the user" Out of curiosity: do you know of any other app that does specifically this? As a user, I'd probably immediately uninstall any app that does this.

Comment: I thought that's possible but it seems it's not, thank you.@FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I had tried lot of ways to open app when received notification, but it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to automatically open an app on the receipt of an FCM message.

As a user, I'd probably immediately uninstall any app that does this.